# Executing a stored procedure twice using TAdoStoredProc in Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin and I needed to use TAdoStoredProc in my project. I don't use any non-visual component in my forms or data modules. All my connection and db components are creating at run-time.

**My Question**: When I'm trying to execute TAdoStoredProc, it executes twice and my insert, update processes have worked twice.

```
var
  mSp: TADOStoredProc;
  i: Integer;
begin
  mSp := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
  mSp.Connection := conn;
  mSp.ProcedureName := spname;
  mSp.CommandTimeout := 600;
  mSp.parameters.Refresh;
  for i := 0 to parameters.Count - 1 do
  begin
    mSp.parameters.ParamByName(parameters[i].Name).Value := parameters[i].Value;
  end;
  mSp.ExecProc;
  mSp.Open;
  Result := mSp;
```

What should I do or change? Thanks.

Comment: if you need a resultset after executing the stored proc, call `Open` if not call `Execproc` but not both!

Answer (score 4):

As I see that your code required some return values. So you should use **`TAdoStoredProc`** like **`TAdoQuery`**. You don't need to use `ExecProc` function for execute, try to use only `Open` function.

You can just check out TADOStoredProc.ExecProc Method [documentation from here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOStoredProc_ExecProc.html).

> If an application is only interested in the result set returned by a stored procedure, **call Open method for the TADOStoredProc component** or set its Active property to true.